# Apply icon styling on md-button

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am using [ng2-material library](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material) (built on top of angular2). The [documentation](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/) and demos are clearly out dated and not updated as per the new angular 2 release. However, having made the necessary adjustments so far, I want a menu icon inside a button which is located on the toolbar of the page. I am able to load the material icon of menu, but still cannot give it a `button-icon` styling. This is how I am doing it:

```
<button md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
  <i class="mdclass-dark material-icons" md-icon >menu</i>
</button>
```

This is giving the menu icon the styling, that of a button, rather than that of an md-icon.. Can someone please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `md-icon-button` directive instead of `md-button`.

and you can also use `<md-icon>` element instead of `<i>` to display material icons.

```
<button md-icon-button aria-label="Settings">
  <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
</button>
```